# How to define log severity level in Fluentd Java API?

Tags: java, logging, fluentd

I am trying to log my Kafka Java application using Fleuntd. The logs are written to files on a server. The problem is I cannot set log severity in a fine-grained manner. This is the simple line of code I get my logger with:

```java
private static FluentLogger logger = FluentLogger.getLogger(Configs.getConfig("loggerName"),
            Configs.getConfig("fluentHost"), Integer.parseInt(Configs.getConfig("fluentPort")));
```

I looked through the Fluentd Java API but found nothing for setting log level.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: @Kugutsumen actually no, and I ended up not using fluentd